# Warning: require_once(__DIR__/db_connect.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, android

I am developing an Android app, and i am trying to **`connect my app with PHP Database through PHP API.`** And i am using `web host to run my PHP scripts,`

But when i use following code. i am getting an error that : `There is no such file.`

if someone can help me in this, it will be a good help for me .

```
<?php

   require_once(__DIR__ . '/db_connect.php');

?>
```

Comment: what have you written in your code to include this `db_connect.php`?

Comment: What's the value of `__DIR__`? Please check with `print_r`.

Comment: i m not getting the basic url of that file . i have tried so many times, but getting an error. :(

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

 
    // connecting to db

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

 





$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( event_id ) as total_event FROM eventtbl; ");


this is my code, and i have hosted my php script at my free web host

Comment: hey,,, i got solution,, thank u so much.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **DIR** is NOT within apostrophe ('), so your line of code should look like this:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/db_connect.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/file.php';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!